# Creating new User Google admin sdk python

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm getting an error that google doesn't recognize the user names in the json. I cannot find a way to include the http header application/json. The return URL gives me another error code but I pass login authentication.

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import requests
import json
import pprint

# Setup the Admin SDK Directory API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'
#Global scope for access to all user and user alias operations.
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
# Call the Admin SDK Directory API
userInfo = {
    "name" : {
        "givenName" : "Donald",
        "familyName" : "Dump",
    },
    "kind" : "user",
    "primaryEmail" : "testUser@test.com",
    "isAdmin": False,
    "isDelegatedAdmin": False,
    "agreedToTerms": True,
    "password": "testpass1234",
    "changePasswordAtNextLogin": True  
}
response = service.users().insert(body=json.dumps(userInfo)).execute()
```

[image: Error code]
[image: Positional Wrapper _helpers.py]
[image: Link that produced HttpError 400]

Comment: Updated the boolean values, now getting a new error with the positional_wrapper from the googleapiclient

Comment: Instead of using images, can you instead copy the text and post the updated error here? What's a positional_wrapper error btw?

Comment: How did you solve the "Invalid Given/Family Name: FamilyName" error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with Google APIs, but I believe it's expecting a valid JSON, so we have a problem in the code even before sending the request itself.
So, before going any further, you should fix your declared dictionary:
Writing `"isAdmin": "false",` is not okay, because True/False are booleans, however you're sending them as a string.
You should write `"isAdmin": False,` instead. If editing the json file itself, write `false`, because in python the booleans start with a capital letter, but not in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add my 50cc.
This code works for me.

```
admin_user_payload = {
 "status": "true"
 } 

request = service.users().makeAdmin(userKey='admin_user_key', body=admin_user_payload)
admin = request.execute()
```

where `admin_user_key` should be for example `info@myaccount.com`. I mean it's the userKey.

`isAdmin` in the payload user insert is ignored by default. For making an user admin you should use the method `makeAdmin` passing userKey (the user email is valid) and the payload with status:true.

Below you can find all API docs.

https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.users.html